How to center a div vertically when the parent div doesn't have a defined height
How can I vertically center div-4 on the page on different viewports (mobile, desktop, and iPad)? Note that the parent divs don't have a defined size.


.div-3 {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="div-1">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="toolbar">
    <button></button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="div-2">
    <div class="div-3">
      <div class="div-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




what have you tried? have you tried resizing each height of each divs to 100% ?

When using flex-direction: column, vertical position is controlled by justify-content, not by align-items.

centre div-4 relative to what? its parent or the viewport?

I turned the div-4 into a p element and added borders just so that you can see it better.
When you want to dynamically center elements (horizontally or vertically) flexbox is a very good beginner friendly way to start. And you were in the right track.
When there is only one child I prefer to use row instead of column (it's my go-to I guess xD). In this case I used row and I centered it vertically (align-items) and horizontally (justify-content).
If you really want to use column then it's the other way around: vertically -> justify-content, horizontally -> align-items.


.div-3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.div-2 {border: solid 1px yellow;}
.div-4 {border: solid 1px blue;}
<div class="div-1">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <button></button>
    </div>
    <div class="div-2">
       <div class="div-3">
            <p class="div-4"> Div-4
            </p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>



When I was first learning flexbox this guide saved me: Flexbox Guide
Also, you can clearly see flexbox in action in this W3S tutorial Flexbox Tutorial
Maybe these will help you too!
Hope this helped! Keep up the good work :)
